# Why does typeof Function.prototype return "function" instead of "object"?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In JavaScript, why typeof Function.prototype is “function”, not “object” like other prototype objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859308/in-javascript-why-typeof-function-prototype-is-function-not-object-like-oth)

Question says it all. All of the following return "object":

```
typeof Array.prototype
typeof Date.prototype
typeof String.prototype
```

But the following returns "function":

```
typeof Function.prototype
```

I thought all prototypes were objects?