# Why's there no a prototype property on Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming, prototype

This question is a bit pedantic. You've been warned beforehand :)

I noticed something and I thought of sharing it with you. Let's get straight to it.

Since **all functions are supposed to have a prototype property** that's epicenter of the prototypical inheritance model in js, and since `Function.prototype` is a function in itself, you'd expect to see a `prototype` property on the prototype object that all functions in js get their methods and properties from by virtue of *inheritance* but nothing there.

Is there a logical explanation behind this decision to omit the `prototype` on that particular function or it was dropped just for stylistic reasons since `Function.prototype.prototype` might look ugly for some, or maybe the `prototype` prop on the `Function` constructor is like for the lack of a better term the *god* of all prototypes in js and thus can't have a `prototype` property itself?

Looking forward to your answers.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if your browser reports "function", [prototypes are objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), or null.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859308/in-javascript-why-typeof-function-prototype-is-function-not-object-like-ot?rq=1

Comment: Should I then close this a exact duplicate?

Comment: `Function.prototype` is a special case of the "all prototypes are objects" statement  but I am not even asking about this here. I'm asking specifically about `Function.prototype.prototype`.

@BuhakeSindi I plead to you that you leave this question open for other people to chime in and provide their input.

Comment: not all that much really. Object don't need to have prototypes, so the fact that Function.prototype does not itself have a prototype is hardly surprising in any way. The only surprise is when you think that the `typeof` evaluation of `Function.prototype` tells us what it truly is. Barmar's link is an excellent follow up on the spec section I reference.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Propably `Array.isArray(Array.prototype)  //true` is not an array either ...

Comment: correct. it's an object definition that is *used* by the `isArray` function to determine whether something's an array, so it's not an array, and `isArray` will say it is.

Comment: and probably the addition of `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply`, `Function.prototype.bind` is just a sinister plot by extraterrestrials to mislead us humans to believe that `Function.prototype` is a function when it's a 100% pure object. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: ... what is wrong with you. The function prototype **is** the object that houses the apply, call, etc **Function prototype functions**, of course you can call those. Read the spec linked in this answer and the one given by Barmar. In fact, read the entire spec, it's kind of a cool read with lots of insight on why ES5 does what it does.

Comment: Again: yes. You're not saying anything new, or contradictory to the answers given so far. At this point I can only assume you've refused to read http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.3.1 and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4 and are just making things up for the sake of arguing, so let's cut that short: The answer to your original question has been supplied, with links to the most authoritative resource possible: ECMA-262. Please read that, and move on.

Answer (score 0):

*"all functions are supposed to have a prototype property"*

That has never been true, and is even less true in ES6:

```
Array.prototype.slice.hasOwnProperty('prototype')  // false
let f = () => {}
f.hasOwnProperty('prototype')  // false
let o = { m() {} }
o.m.hasOwnProperty('prototype')  // false
class C { m() {} }
(new C).m.hasOwnProperty('prototype')  // false
```

JavaScript distinguishes between functions, and functions that are constructors.

Comment: Please distinguish between an **OWN** property and an _inherited_ property fetched from the prototype chain of every function.

The `hasOwnProperty` method only checks for own props nothing more and nothing less.