# Function.prototype is a function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm digging into the Javascript prototype chain.
In order to document my findings, I've drawn the following scheme:

[image]

Although most of the concepts are clear, I'm left with just two related questions. Rather than splitting them up, I guessed that centralising them in this question might be better:

1. Is there a reason for `Function.prototype` to be of type function, instead of object?
   `typeof Function.prototype; //"function"`
2. Is `Function.prototype` a 'unique function' in JS since it doesn't have a prototype property of its own like other functions do? (is there a generally accepted 'name' to refer to it?)

Comment: notice that `function Person (){} typeof Person.prototype //"object"`

Comment: functions are also objects

Comment: Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype

Comment: This reference from mozilla might help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got confused by the wording of your question. I thought that by "doesn't have a prototype" you were talking about `[[Prototype]]` internal member. Now I see you were referring to the `prototype` property.

Comment: @StefanBaiu Oh I see what you mean, I rephrased, should have mentioned property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, why typeof Function.prototype is "function", not "object" like other prototype objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859308/in-javascript-why-typeof-function-prototype-is-function-not-object-like-ot)

Comment: That question, explains why it is a function not why they chose it to be function instead of an object.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason is that [the ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4) says so:

> The Function prototype object is itself a Function object (its
>   [[Class]] is "Function") that, when invoked, accepts any arguments and
>   returns undefined.

Note it's common in ES5 to make the prototype of some class a member of that class:

- [`Object.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4) is an Object object.
- [`Function.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4) is a Function object which returns `undefined` when invoked.
- [`Array.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4) is an empty Array object.
- [`String.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4) is a String object whose value is an empty String.
- [`Boolean.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.4) is a Boolean object whose value is `false`.
- [`Number.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4) is a Number object whose value is `+0`.
- [`Date.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5) is a Date object whose [[PrimitiveValue]] is `NaN`.
- [`RegExp.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6) is a RegExp object whose data properties are like `new RegExp()`'s ones.
- [`Error.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.4) is an Error object.

I think it was standardized as such because the prototype of a class has the intrinsic properties of that class, as the instances of that class. And if it [looks like a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) it should behave as a duck. So calling the methods of the prototype on the prototype itself instead of on an instance should work too.

However, ES6 didn't like this. So it changed the behavior for those:

- [`Boolean.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-boolean-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[BooleanData]] internal slot.
- [`Error.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-error-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[ErrorData]] internal slot.
- [`Number.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-number-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[NumberData]] internal slot.
- [`Date.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-date-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[DateValue]] internal slot.
- [`String.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-string-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[StringData]] internal slot.
- [`RegExp.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-regexp-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[RegExpMatcher]] nor any of the other internal slots of RegExp instance objects.

And also for new "classes" <sub><sup>(ES6 objects no longer have a [[Class]])</sup></sub>:

- [`Symbol.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-symbol-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[SymbolData]] internal slot.
- [`TypedArray.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-typedarray-prototype-objects) is an ordinary object with no [[ViewedArrayBuffer]] nor any other of the internal slots that are specific to *TypedArray* instance objects.
- [`Map.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-map-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[MapData]] internal slot.
- [`Set.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-set-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[SetData]] internal slot.
- [`WeakMap.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-weakmap-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[WeakMapData]] internal slot.
- [`WeakSet.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-weakset-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[WeakSetData]] internal slot.
- [`ArrayBuffer.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-arraybuffer-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no  [[ArrayBufferData]] nor [[ArrayBufferByteLength]] internal slots.
- [`DataView.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-dataview-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[DataView]], [[ViewedArrayBuffer]], [[ByteLength]], nor [[ByteOffset]] internal slots.
- [`GeneratorFunction.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-generatorfunction-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no  [[ECMAScriptCode]] nor any other of the internal slots listed in [Table 27](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-27) or [Table 56](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-56).
- [`Promise.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-promise-prototype-object) is an ordinary object with no [[PromiseState]] nor any of the other internal slots of Promise instances.

However, the old behavior remains for those:

- [`Function.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object) is itself a built-in function object.
- [`Array.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) is an Array exotic object and has the internal methods specified for such objects.

So now the reason is backwards compatibility:

> The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to
>   ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to
>   the ECMAScript 2015 specification.

Note this doesn't make `Function.prototype` a special function. Only constructors have  the [`prototype` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-prototype):

> Function instances that can be used as a constructor have a `prototype`
>   property.

There are multiple examples of non-constructor functions apart from `Function.prototype`, such as

- Methods in `Math` object:

  ```js
  typeof Math.pow; // "function
  'prototype' in Math.pow; // false
  ```
- Some host objects:

  ```js
  typeof document.createElement('object'); // "function
  'prototype' in document.createElement('object'); // false
  ```
- In ES6, arrow functions:

  ```js
  typeof (x => x * x); // "function
  'prototype' in (x => x * x); // false
  ```

Comment: Mother of javascript. And when I thought it could no longer surprise me

Answer (score 8):

In answer to your questions:

**1)** `Function.prototype` is a type of function because, according to ECMAScript 2015:

> The Function prototype object is the intrinsic object %FunctionPrototype%. The Function prototype object is itself a built-in function object.
>
> The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification.

So the Function prototype object is only defined as a Function object to ensure compatability with older ECMAScript standards. The function doesn't actually do anything:

> When invoked, it accepts any arguments and returns undefined.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object

**2)** Regarding the prototype property:

> The Function prototype object does not have a prototype property.

[Same Source](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object)

This is unique since all functions usually possess a `prototype` property, however since the Function prototype object is only specified as a Function object to maintain compatability, it's behaviour is unlike that of regular functions.

I've created a JSFiddle with various tests in case it helps anyone:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ld0b39xz/

```
// We'll use 'Object.getPrototypeOf' to access [[prototype]]

// As you know, [[prototype]] of Object.prototype returns 'null'. 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype));
// null

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Let's take a closer look at Function.prototype
console.log(Function.prototype);
// Output:
// function(){}

// This is what the specs say should happen:
// "The Function prototype object is itself a built-in function object."

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Let's see if this function has a 'prototype' property.
// All functions normally have a prototype property that initially
// references an empty object...except this one.
var fn = Function.prototype;
console.log(fn.prototype);
// Output:
// undefined

// This is expected, according to the specs:
// "The Function prototype object does not have a prototype property."

// It does have some properties such as 'name' and 'length',
// but not 'prototype'.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Let's see what [[prototype]] of Function.prototype returns.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype));
// Output:
// Object{}

// Again this is expected:
// "The value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the
// Function prototype object is the intrinsic object %ObjectPrototype%"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Now lets see what the [[Prototype]] of this object is:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype)));
// Output:
// null

// We've come full circle since all the statement above is
// doing is looking for the prototoype of the native Object,
// which we already know is 'null' from our first test.
```

Answer (score 3):

*In replacement of a previous answer which I could not stand by. With thanks to Oriol. The head scratching is mine.*

In regards the first question the Function object it not particularly different simply because `Function.prototype` is a function. Other built in constructors use prototype objects of their own type. What draws attention to the Function case is that the `typeof` operator treats function objects diffently to other objects by returning "function" instead of "object".

Global constructors listing themselves as constructors of their prototype objects:

```
var BuiltIn = Function; // for example
BuiltIn.prototype.constructor == BuiltIn // true
```

is more or less documentary. Prototype objects of built in constructors generally have methods which interface with the javascript engine and are not created using a javascript call to their listed constructor as it appears at run time: `Function.prototype instanceof Function` is false with similar results for other built in constructors such as Array, RegExp etc tested.

The global `Function` object is unique, however, in that it lists itself as is its own constructor (`Function.constructor == Function` is true), and that it is an instance of itself (`Function instanceof Function` is true as well). The latter result indicates that `Function.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `Function`.  `Function.prototype` itself is prototyped on `Object.prototype`.

Another reason to think `Function.prototype` is not a Function object in the usual sense (apart from saying so in the documentation) is that it cannot be called as a constructor and throws an error if an attempt is made to do so. Since the prototype property of a function is used when the function is called as a constructor, it makes sense for `Function.prototype` not to have this property.

Comment: Many other built-in JavaScript functions and arrow functions cannot be called as constructors.