# Constructor concept in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor

In one of my questions, I got the following code as one of the answers. My understanding of the language has come has come a far better now,
just have one small question.

```
var person = function() {
     this.firstName = "";
     this.lastName = "";
} 

person.prototype.showFullName = function () { 
     console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName); 
} 

var perObj = new person();
perObj.firstName = "Penelope";
perObj.lastName = "Barrymore";
perObj.showFullName();
```

Considering the object,

```
var person = function() {
     this.firstName = "";
     this.lastName = "";
}
```

and when I call this object using,

```
var perObj = new person();
```

Is this similar to constructor kind of thing?

The moment a code

```
var perObj = new person();
```

is invoked will the following two lines automatically get executed?

```
 this.firstName = "";
 this.lastName = "";
```

And also in one of the blogs I was studying if the file name is `Samplescript.js` and if a function is written using the same name inside this like `var Samplescript=function(){}`, will this function be considered a constructor?
Please clarify me this.

I am not getting any satisfying answer regarding constructor practically even though theoretically things are clear, in this example the way its written makes lot of clear understanding.

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor this might help you

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Yes, `person` *is* a constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all the `person` is a regular JavaScript function. When you call it, of course, lines:

```
this.firstName = "";
this.lastName = "";
```

are executed. *Constructor function* is rather a concept than a something really existing in the JS language. You need constructors to create new similar objects by calling `new MyCtr()`. At the same time you need regular functions to encapsulate piece of logic and make it reusable in different places without copy/paste the code.

You can use all functions in JavaScript as a constructor. Just add `new` keyword in front of function call expression. This thing changes the *context* of execution of the function. Without `new` the function is executed against *global* object (`window` in a browser). And `this` variable inside the function refers to the context.

Not every function is ready to be a constructor. Usually, *constructor functions* are doing something with `this` variable which is a reference to an object which is created during `new MyCtr()` call. Also, *constructor functions* never return a value.

Lets look at few examples (you can execute it directly in the browser's console):

```
function foo() {
    this.a = 1;
}

foo();  // using function as a regular function. Ctx is window.
console.log(window.a);  // prints "1"
foo.call(window);  // explicitly specify execution ctx. The same as just foo() call

var instance = new foo();  // using foo as a constructor
console.log(instance.a);   // prints "1"

// actually you can do it without new keyword
var instance = {};  // manually create new object
foo.call(instance); // manually call foo against this object
console.log(instance.a);   // prints "1"

// However, the code above is not strictly equivalent to the code using new. 
// It omits the concept of prototype, but it's enough for our current task.
```

Regarding functions and files. There is no such thing in the language like in the Java that each class must be placed in the separate file. You can put all your functions within one file and then use it as constructors or not. However, the best practice is to reside one constructor function (read as *class*) per one file (called module).

Comment: "*You can use all functions in JavaScript as a constructor.*" - not true. There are constructible objects and callable objects, and not all of them are both. (the ones created using the `function` keyword are, though)

Comment: @Bergi, do you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928810/function-prototype-is-a-function#32929083? (please, look at the end of the answer)

Comment: Yes, ES6 arrows and methods and others.

Comment: Great! Thanks alot for your comment. It's very useful.

Answer (score 8):

**any function in JavaScript can act as a constructor when the function is invoked with new operator**.

Now, what a constructor does ?  **it creates/instantiate an object from the constructor function.**  like its shown in the below image.

[image]

[LINK](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/)   , it explain the fundamentals very clearly.

what is `this` ?

when this constructor function is invoked with new, `this` points to the new object created at that invocation. and in that object we set `firtName` and `lastName` (it is the initialization of the new object created).

Now when we add methods to the prototype of the constructor , that is being shared between all the objects created using the constructor function(picture explains it lit bit more)

**and regarding your last query**
"And also in one of the blogs I was studying if the file name is Samplescript.js and if a function is written using the same name inside this like var Samplescript=function(){}, will this function be considered a constructor? Please clarify me this"

**any function in JavaScript can act as a constructor when the function is invoked with new operator, and its not the way that blog says**.

so please stop reading that blog, the link i provided is a very good starting point

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the link. Though I don't have time to go through it now, it seems very informative and valuable.

Answer (score 4):

There appear to be some holes in your understanding. Hopefully I can help.

First, the traditional conventional syntax for a *constructor function* is `function CapitalisedFunctionName()`

```
function Person() {
  this.firstName = "";
  this.lastName = "";
}
```

Note: *this is not an object*. From your question this isn't clear you understand that.

At this point you can add to the prototype from which all new objects created from that constructor will inherit. This modified method from your example will be available to all new objects.

```
Person.prototype.fullname = function () { 
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

Now, the constructor function allows you to create new *object instances*. So when you write:

```
var perObj = new person();
```

you are *calling the constructor function*, *creating a new object instance*, and assigning that instance to the `perObj` variable.

When you create a new object instance the object contains the `firstName` and `lastName` properties which can be accessed like so:

```
perObj.firstName;
perObj.lastName;
```

Note at the moment these have only empty strings assigned to them.

And you can call that method too:

```
perObj.fullname();
```

But, again, at this point, `perObj.fullname();` won't give you anything because `firstName` and `lastName` are empty strings.

You can either define them like you have in your example: `perObj.lastName = 'Jones', or you could even change the way you *create* the object in the first place which is often the preferred method:

Consider this:

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
}

var perObj = new Person('Dave', 'Jones');
```

Now `perObj` will have those properties prefilled:

```
perObj.firstName // Dave
perObj.lastName // Jones
perObj.fullname() // Dave Jones
```

Comment: To be precise, the `Person` IS object by itself. However, I agree, that it's not so important for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Any function that is called with `new` operator acts as a constructor, so `this` will be assigned to the new object and points to it. Also the code inside the constructor will be executed and the new object (`perObj`) will get properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to define Javascript classes and invoke them with a constructor. But remember that JavaScript is actually classless.

1. Use a function
2. The use of Object literals
3. A singleton using a function

An excellent article about it can be found here: [3 ways to define a Javascript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)