# Is Function.prototype the only function without a prototype property?

Tags: javascript

Is `Function.prototype` the only function without a `prototype` property?

Why is the property absent instead of having a `prototype` property with a value of `null`.

```js
document.write(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Function.prototype));
```

Edit: presumably the `prototype` property is elided because it does not have a `[[Construct]]` internal method (it is not a constructor).

Comment: I don't know if the "why" is relevant, it just is, but here's what the spec says http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object

Comment: Perhaps the NOTE in that section explains why Function.prototype is a function at all

Comment: This was part of [Function.prototype is a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32928810/1529630), but probably that should have been split into multiple questions, so I don't think this should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, just found that [section 9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-built-in-function-objects) para 6 says:

> Built-in functions that are not constructors do not have a prototype property unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function.

All "normal" functions have the `[[Construct]]` internal method ([section 9.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-functionallocate)):

> If functionKind is "normal", let needsConstruct be true.

Exotic built-in functions may or may not have the `[[Construct]]` internal method and if they do not, then they do not have the `prototype` property, "unless otherwise specified".

Answer (score 1):

Only constructors have  the [`prototype` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-prototype):

> Function instances that can be used as a constructor have a `prototype`
>   property.

There are multiple examples of non-constructor functions apart from `Function.prototype`, such as

- Methods in `Math` object:

  ```js
  typeof Math.pow; // "function"
  'prototype' in Math.pow; // false
  ```
- Some host objects:

  ```js
  typeof document.createElement('object'); // "function"
  'prototype' in document.createElement('object'); // false
  ```
- In ES6, arrow functions:

  ```js
  typeof (x => x * x); // "function"
  'prototype' in (x => x * x); // false
  ```

Comment: Do you know of any exotic non-constructor functions with the `prototype` own property as the spec appears to leave room for? (section 9.3 para 6: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-built-in-function-objects)

Comment: @BenAston I don't know any native example. I don't think there is any point in having a `prototype` property if the function is not a constructor.