# Function.prototype and Funciton.__proto__

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Can anybody explain/elaborate on the following:

[image]

I have checked this on console.

`Function.prototype` and `Function.__proto__` point to the same object. It is also the same object that is referenced by `Object.__proto__`.
Any custom function that you write or even the built-ins one (Array,String,Number) , have their `.__proto__` point to this object.

Checking Function.prototype on console returns:

```
ƒ () { [native code] }
```

Interestingly, this object's `.__proto__` point to `Object.prototype` object.

I do understand that `Object.prototype.__proto__` is null which is where the prototype chain stops.

Found the image [here](https://kenneth-kin-lum.blogspot.com/2012/10/javascripts-pseudo-classical.html)

Comment: This might help you understand - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: Every function (including `Function()` and `Object()`) inherits from `Function.prototype`, which holds function methods like `.call`/`.apply`/`.bind`, and in turn inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi Does this not look strange to you that the Function object has its both .__proto__ and .prototype property point to a same object. String.prototype and String.__proto__ point to two different objects.
Moreover, what exactly is Function.prototype object? I can't see what is inside it. It returns ƒ () { [native code] }. Is it of type function or object. You can see what is inside Function() object, Object() and Obect.prototype object. But not this one.

Comment: @GowthamRajJ, thanks, I had a look at Mozilla docs, but could not find something useful that sheds light on this.

Comment: @pragun Use `console.dir` to print it as an object - `Function.prototype` is a function for some reason. And no, `Function.prototype === Obect.getPrototypeOf(Function)` isn't strange if you consider what they mean, but it's special indeed as this only happens on a "metaclass" where the class is an instance of itself.

Comment: The reason why `Function.prototype` remains a `Function` object is due to backwards compatibility. Basically, there is a change in ES specification regarding how should a prototype object of an object be treated. For eg, in ES5, `String.prototype` is an `String` object but in ES6, its an object of type `Object`. The exception to such changes are "prototype objects" of `Function` and `Array`.  You can read more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928810/function-prototype-is-a-function